# Finding the average and the standard deviation of three data sets

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, data-visualization

I have a laser that is sent through a signal splitter. 90% of the light goes into a diffuser and that is detected by a Photomultiplier tube (PMT). The other 10% of the signal goes to a separate silicon photodiode that is used to monitor the power of the laser during diffuser testing. The diffuser is rotated through a range of -60° to +60° and stops every 3° to record the area of the optical signal from both the PMT and the photodiode (this is referred to as one scan). The photodiode data is in terms of (x,y) = ([angle], [area]).  I want to calculate the average and the standard deviation for the photodiode area at each angular position of the diffuser.

So say for three sets of photodiode areas:

diode1 = ([-60,-57,-54,-51,-48,-45,-42,-39,-36,-33,-30,-27,-24,-21,-18,-15,-12,-9,-6,-3,0,3,6,9,12,15,18,21,24,27,30,33,36,39,42,45,48,51,54,57,60],[0.01011,0.01007,0.01013,0.01005,0.01014,0.01018,0.01013,0.01021,0.01020,0.01020,0.01019,0.01028,0.01021,0.01026,0.01025,0.01020,0.01024,0.01029,0.01019,0.01023,0.01027,0.01019,0.01031,0.01030,0.01031,0.01034,0.01021,0.01019,0.01019,0.01025,0.01034,0.01020,0.01024,0.01029,0.01011,0.01013,0.01025,0.01013,0.01025,0.01004,0.01003])

diode2 = ([-60,-57,-54,-51,-48,-45,-42,-39,-36,-33,-30,-27,-24,-21,-18,-15,-12,-9,-6,-3,0,3,6,9,12,15,18,21,24,27,30,33,36,39,42,45,48,51,54,57,60],[0.01016,0.01004,0.01019,0.01023,0.01018,0.01022,0.01036,0.01027,0.01023,0.01034,0.01033,0.01026,0.01028,0.01040,0.01035,0.01034,0.01032,0.01039,0.01021,0.01036,0.01035,0.01025,0.01024,0.01035,0.01034,0.01030,0.01028,0.01038,0.01020,0.01024,0.01028,0.01017,0.01014,0.01025,0.01022,0.01025,0.01022,0.01025,0.01022,0.01025,0.01021,0.01006,0.01021,001020,0.01012])

diode3 = ([-60,-57,-54,-51,-48,-45,-42,-39,-36,-33,-30,-27,-24,-21,-18,-15,-12,-9,-6,-3,0,3,6,9,12,15,18,21,24,27,30,33,36,39,42,45,48,51,54,57,60],[0.009954,0.01001,0.01001,0.01010,0.009978,0.01004,0.01010,0.01010,0.01009,0.01003,0.01008,0.01004,0.01007,0.01008,0.01015,0.01016,0.01017,0.01011,0.01031,0.01003,0.01001,0.01015,0.01015,0.01014,0.01008,0.01016,0.01022,0.01005,0.01009,0.01014,0.01012,0.009989,0.01004,0.01008,0.009914,0.009974,0.009973,0.009958,0.01023,0.01008,0.009901])

The x values are the same for each data set because they're just repeated scans. I am interested in calculating the average and standard deviation for the y values at each corresponding x angle. I hope that makes sense and thank you in advance for the help!

Comment: I tried to answer to the question you posted here, unfortunately, I can't do anything if the question you posted doesn't ask for the issue you want to solve. I tried to answer to this question, so evaluate it for its purpose

Answer (score 1):

You can organize your data in a [**`pandas.DataFrame`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html), where you have a column for angle values, then a column for each diode:

```
columns = ['diode1', 'diode2', 'diode3']
diodes = [diode1, diode2, diode3]

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['angle'] = diode1[0]
for col, d in zip(columns, diodes):
    df[col] = d[1]
```

Then you can easily compute mean and standard deviation for each row (angle value) with:

```
df['mean'] = df[columns].mean(axis = 1)
df['std'] = df[columns].std(axis = 1)
```

With the data you provided you would get something like:

```
    angle   diode1   diode2    diode3      mean       std
0     -60  0.01011  0.01016  0.009954  0.010075  0.000107
1     -57  0.01007  0.01004  0.010010  0.010040  0.000030
2     -54  0.01013  0.01019  0.010010  0.010110  0.000092
3     -51  0.01005  0.01023  0.010100  0.010127  0.000093
4     -48  0.01014  0.01018  0.009978  0.010099  0.000107
5     -45  0.01018  0.01022  0.010040  0.010147  0.000095
6     -42  0.01013  0.01036  0.010100  0.010197  0.000142
7     -39  0.01021  0.01027  0.010100  0.010193  0.000086
8     -36  0.01020  0.01023  0.010090  0.010173  0.000074
9     -33  0.01020  0.01034  0.010030  0.010190  0.000155
10    -30  0.01019  0.01033  0.010080  0.010200  0.000125
...
```

Then, if you want to draw a plot:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(df['angle'], df['mean'], label = 'mean')
ax.plot(df['angle'], df['mean'] + df['std'], label = 'mean + std')
ax.plot(df['angle'], df['mean'] - df['std'], label = 'mean - std')

ax.legend(frameon = True)
ax.set_xlabel('angle (deg)')
ax.set_ylabel('area')

plt.show()
```

### Complete code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd


diode1 = ([-60,-57,-54,-51,-48,-45,-42,-39,-36,-33,-30,-27,-24,-21,-18,-15,-12,-9,-6,-3,0,3,6,9,12,15,18,21,24,27,30,33,36,39,42,45,48,51,54,57,60],[0.01011,0.01007,0.01013,0.01005,0.01014,0.01018,0.01013,0.01021,0.01020,0.01020,0.01019,0.01028,0.01021,0.01026,0.01025,0.01020,0.01024,0.01029,0.01019,0.01023,0.01027,0.01019,0.01031,0.01030,0.01031,0.01034,0.01021,0.01019,0.01019,0.01025,0.01034,0.01020,0.01024,0.01029,0.01011,0.01013,0.01025,0.01013,0.01025,0.01004,0.01003])
diode2 = ([-60,-57,-54,-51,-48,-45,-42,-39,-36,-33,-30,-27,-24,-21,-18,-15,-12,-9,-6,-3,0,3,6,9,12,15,18,21,24,27,30,33,36,39,42,45,48,51,54,57,60],[0.01016,0.01004,0.01019,0.01023,0.01018,0.01022,0.01036,0.01027,0.01023,0.01034,0.01033,0.01026,0.01028,0.01040,0.01035,0.01034,0.01032,0.01039,0.01021,0.01036,0.01035,0.01025,0.01024,0.01035,0.01034,0.01030,0.01028,0.01038,0.01020,0.01024,0.01028,0.01017,0.01014,0.01025,0.01022,0.01025,0.01022,0.01025,0.01022,0.01025,0.01021])
diode3 = ([-60,-57,-54,-51,-48,-45,-42,-39,-36,-33,-30,-27,-24,-21,-18,-15,-12,-9,-6,-3,0,3,6,9,12,15,18,21,24,27,30,33,36,39,42,45,48,51,54,57,60],[0.009954,0.01001,0.01001,0.01010,0.009978,0.01004,0.01010,0.01010,0.01009,0.01003,0.01008,0.01004,0.01007,0.01008,0.01015,0.01016,0.01017,0.01011,0.01031,0.01003,0.01001,0.01015,0.01015,0.01014,0.01008,0.01016,0.01022,0.01005,0.01009,0.01014,0.01012,0.009989,0.01004,0.01008,0.009914,0.009974,0.009973,0.009958,0.01023,0.01008,0.009901])

columns = ['diode1', 'diode2', 'diode3']
diodes = [diode1, diode2, diode3]

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['angle'] = diode1[0]
for col, d in zip(columns, diodes):
    df[col] = d[1]

df['mean'] = df[columns].mean(axis = 1)
df['std'] = df[columns].std(axis = 1)


fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(df['angle'], df['mean'], label = 'mean')
ax.plot(df['angle'], df['mean'] + df['std'], label = 'mean + std')
ax.plot(df['angle'], df['mean'] - df['std'], label = 'mean - std')

ax.legend(frameon = True)
ax.set_xlabel('angle (deg)')
ax.set_ylabel('area')

plt.show()
```

[image]

---

**Note**
In data you provided may be an error: `diode1` and `diode3` have 41 values for both angles and area. On the contrary, `diode2` has **41** values for angles but **45** values for area, so there is a mismatch. Please check your data for `diode2`.

Comment: Thank you so much. Unfortunately, I asked the wrong thing here. I was half asleep when I posted this and did not realize my mistake. I re-posted the question, this time more carefully. It is actually the PMT data I want the standard deviation of, the photodiode is only used for normalization. If you have a chance can you look at my new question? It is similar to this one. Thank you again for  the help.